# What is the exact length of the belt, in inches?

Tags: geometry

56. As shown below, 2 circular pulleys with centers 8 inches apart are connected with a tight belt. The belt wraps 2/3 of the way around the larger pulley, which has a radius of 5 inches, and 1/3 of the way around the smaller pulley, which has a radius of 1  inch. What is the exact length of the belt, in inches?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? I would start by drawing triangles inside the circles ...

Comment: What do you mean by "$2$ of the way" and "+ of the way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Add some lines to get something like

[image]

You know $AC=5$ and $BD=1$ and $CD=8$ so using similar triangles you can find $DG$ and $CG$.  That will give you $AG$ using Pythagoras and thus $AB$ and by symmetry $EF$.

You can find $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$ from the "$2/3$ of the way around the larger pulley ... and $1/3$ of the way around the smaller pulley" or from the sides of the triangles.  You can use this to find the length of these curved arcs.

Add up the lengths of belt

Answer (score 1):

(Click on the diagram for better viewing.)
[image]

(Took me quite a while to make this diagram. But when I first saw the problem, $2/3$rd, $1/3$rd information wasn't given. Assuming tangency of belt, this information isn't even required. Angle can be calculated as shown.)

Length of belt would be $$ \dfrac{240}{360}\cdot 2\pi\cdot 5 + 2\cdot4\sqrt{3} + \dfrac{120}{360}\cdot 2\pi\cdot 1 \Rightarrow G$$